# Parachain lease extension: Swap ParaID as well

Tags: polkadot, parachain, slot, lease, paraid

When swapping two parachain slots as described in [the polkadot wiki](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-auction#lease-extension-with-overlapping-slots), is it also possible to swap the `ParaID`, for example to keep the old `ParaID` and thus avoid issues in regards to XCM when extending the lease?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When swapping between two parachains you are transfering slot information of each one to the other, same thing happens with crowdloan info.

[`swap` is part of registrar pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/6217ef5e29023375876460d3e831d6463c074bdd/runtime/common/src/paras_registrar.rs#L274), and defines that for this case, both paras are parachains at the same time, the logic handling the swap will be defined at runtime level.

```rust
// --snip
// If both chains are currently parachains, there is nothing funny we
// need to do for their lifecycle management, just swap the underlying
// data.
T::OnSwap::on_swap(id, other);
// --snip
```

If we check registrar pallet config on Kusama we can see the following:

```rust
impl paras_registrar::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type Origin = Origin;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type OnSwap = (Crowdloan, Slots); // implementations of OnSwap on these pallets
    type ParaDeposit = ParaDeposit;
    type DataDepositPerByte = DataDepositPerByte;
    type WeightInfo = weights::runtime_common_paras_registrar::WeightInfo<Runtime>;
}
```

So, when swapping, the logic handling the information movement is located in the following pallets, per runtime definition:

- [crowdloan](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/66374ef1f8dce7ce072e5ae7fdff87b660f04a66/runtime/common/src/crowdloan/mod.rs#L819-L823): swapping Funds information between paras.

```rust
impl<T: Config> crate::traits::OnSwap for Pallet<T> {
    fn on_swap(one: ParaId, other: ParaId) {
        Funds::<T>::mutate(one, |x| Funds::<T>::mutate(other, |y| sp_std::mem::swap(x, y)))
    }
}
```

- [slots](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/common/src/slots/mod.rs#L328-L332): swapping Leases information between paras.

```rust
impl<T: Config> crate::traits::OnSwap for Pallet<T> {
    fn on_swap(one: ParaId, other: ParaId) {
        Leases::<T>::mutate(one, |x| Leases::<T>::mutate(other, |y| sp_std::mem::swap(x, y)))
    }
```

Meaning that if there was a parachain, with `ParaId=2222` which is at its last LP, close to the end of its parachain lifecycle, and it swaps with another parachain with `ParaId=3333` that has more LPs, meaning it will be parachain for longer.
`2222` will receive the LPs of `3333`, then we achieve to keep `2222` for longer as a parachain. `3333` in the other hand will end its parachain lifecycle when `2222` was going to, as it holds the `Leases` information that was `2222`'s before the swap.
Similar story with `Funds` info.

So answering your question, `ParaId`s don't swap, but you can make one of them stick for longer, and thus keep on using it, and this doesn't present any kind of problems.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to keep the paraId with overlapping slots by calling the registrar > swap extrinsic.

I agree that non-overlapping slots takes a bit of logistics and planning e.g. making sure you have time allocated for all aspects of securing a new slot (governance, auction, etc) and it is not guaranteed - you could lose the bid.

Always make sure to test this process locally on a test network.

More Info:

- [How can a project prolong a parachain slot lease in Kusama?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2874/how-can-a-project-prolong-a-parachain-slot-lease-in-kusama/2887#2887)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but the question was about swapping `paraID` when swapping slots. Option 2 is risky, because it is not guaranteed that the slot is attained.

Comment: Updated my answer to better reflect your question.

Comment: [Here](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/11817168-4) is an example of a parachain that called swap 7 days ago on Polkadot. You can see that their lease is now 664 days (as of time of writing this).