# Checklist for renewing a parachain slot

Tags: parachain, auctions, lease

A Parachain team is nearing the end of their Kusama parachain lease and they want to renew it. Is there an available checklist of steps they need to do?

Comment: Check this previous answer https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2874/how-can-a-project-prolong-a-parachain-slot-lease-in-kusama?rq=1

Comment: Also another potential area of steps required can be within the Kusama guide at https://guide.kusama.network/docs/learn-auction/#parachain-lease-extension